# Changing Iframe Width/Height in Javascript Based on Anchor Point

Tags: javascript, iframe

Ok, I deal with this all the time in flash but I'm kind of lost in how to accomplish this in Javascript and CSS.  I have an iframe (which by definition doesn't have an overflow property) whose width/height i'm trying to modify.  Is there an easy way to change this value relative to a certain anchor point?  Basically I have an ad that has a contracted and expanded state.  If the expanded state expands leftward or upward, how can i modify the width/height in such a way to display the entire contents of the ad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can absolutely position your ad and anchor it with `bottom` and `right`:

```
.ad {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Then when you increase the height and width, it will expand upwards and leftwards.

Comment: thanks!  how about expanding from the center or some other arbitrary point?

Comment: You have top, bottom, left, and right to work with as anchor points.  You can use all four, or just two along with height and width.  Adjust the values as needed to get the position you want.